# Start a service within docker container

Tags: docker

I can run this container in interactive mode and then start apache service. This works as expected.

```
# docker run -p 81:80 -it shantanuo/adminer
root@7bdfbf548d92:/# /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Is it possible to start container and apache using the same command something like this?

```
docker run -p 81:80 -d  shantanuo/adminer /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

The above command does not start apache service nor starts container.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google is my friend:

```
docker run -p 81:80  -d  shantanuo/adminer /bin/bash -c "/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND "
```

Comment: Be careful, doing this, your process is actually `bash` and not `apache2`. When you send signals to the container (to stop, restart, etc) they will be received by `bash` and not propagated to apache. You might be better off launching with command such as `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND` instead.